# ImageView is not showing after setting it to visible

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, layout-inflater

I have an xml file with two image views, I've set the visibility of both to gone, so I can change their visibility later dynamically by java. But they are not showing when I set them to visible. Here is the code where I set images to visible based on an intent value sent from another activity,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View temp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_row, container, false);
        if (getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("category")!=null && getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("category").equalsIgnoreCase("important")){
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) temp.findViewById(R.id.icon2);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
        else {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) temp.findViewById(R.id.icon); //draft
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        mSimpleCursorAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.notes_row,null, from, to,0);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo_list, container, false);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this); //once this is done onCreateLoader will be called.
        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.notes_list); //findViewById must be called using the rootView because we are inside a fragment.
         text=  (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_list);

        if(mSimpleCursorAdapter.getCount()==0) {

           text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


            if (getActivity().findViewById (R.id.fragment_container)!=null){
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);}//end if.

        listView.setAdapter(mSimpleCursorAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                Cursor cursor = mSimpleCursorAdapter.getCursor();
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {

                    String category= cursor.getString(1);
                    String summary= cursor.getString(2);
                    String description=cursor.getString(3);
                    long id= cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(NotesContract.NotesTable._ID));
                    int locationId= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(NotesContract.NotesTable.COLUMN_LOCATION));

                    String [] retrievedData= {category, summary, description};


                    if (getActivity().findViewById (R.id.fragment_container)!=null){
                        //two pane layout:
                        listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
                        listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);



                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putStringArray("data",retrievedData);
                        /*args.putInt("update", 1);*/
                        args.putLong("id", id);
                        args.putInt("locationId", locationId);
                        mCallback.onlistElementClicked(args );/*this is available in the parent activity*/
                    }

                    else {
                       // one pane layout:

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotesDetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, retrievedData);
                        /*intent.putExtra("update", 1); */ //to indicate that the query should be update not insert.
                        intent.putExtra("id", id);
                        intent.putExtra("locationId", locationId); //whether it is 0 or 1
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }


                }//end outer cursor if.
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

This is the xml file of the layout I am trying to change the images inside it,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/drafticon"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/staricon"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </ImageView>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@+id/TextView01"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <!--text will be set dynamically -->
    </LinearLayout>
```

As can be seen the layout that contains the image views is called notes_row, and I am only using it as a parameter to the SimpleCursorAdapter.

Can any one please help me? I've tried too many methods and nothing worked, I've checked the intent in the if statement and it is not null.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the visibility to gone. Make the following change for the image views change them to invisible rather than gone. In your XML replace

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

With

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Try replacing

```
android:background="@drawable/staricon"
```

With

```
android:src="@drawable/staricon"
```

You are giving width of match parent for the textView in an horizontal linear layout. That might well be the reason for your image view not being displayed.

Change the width of your text view to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need it to be gone because I don't want it to take a space, but even when setting that to invisible images are not showing. Can you please help me know why this is not working?

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer check that and let me know what happened.

Comment: It is not working, I have doubts that the if statement in which the images are changed is not being executed. I've tried a lot to know the reason, can I send you my code to check that? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am uploading a compressed folder of the project on google drive, can you please give me your email so I can share it with you? Thanks.

Comment: keshav113914 @gmail.com

Comment: Thanks, I've sent it, did you receive it?

Comment: Yes.. I have.. will check